# I'm using numel to read and process multiple files one by one. But it barfs when there is tline statement

Tags: matlab

I'm using numel to read and process multiple files one by one. But it barfs when there is tline statement. Here is my code. Can someone help?

```
   ......
    filename = ['20170101.BER' '20170102.BER' '20170103.BER' '20170104.BER'];

    for i = 1:numel(filename)
        fid = fopen(filename,'rt');

        % Read file and find lines with the string 'DATA'
        count=0;
        got1=[];
        got2=[];
        while 1
            tline = fgetl(fid);
              if ~ischar(tline), break, end
                count=count+1;

        count5=0;
        count3=[];
        for(t=1:length(tline)-length(str)+1)
        count4=0;
        for(count2=1:length(str))
        ......

        fclose(fid);

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to [`fgetl`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) fails because `fid` is not a valid file ID. Your main problem is how you are storing and accessing `filename`. What you have right now is a 1-by-N [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html). It's a better idea to store your file names in a [cell array of character arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html), like so:

```
filename = {'20170101.BER' '20170102.BER' '20170103.BER' '20170104.BER'};
```

This is now a 1-by-4 cell array. When you loop over the 4 cells, you have to extract the character array to open the file like so:

```
fid = fopen(filename{i}, 'rt');
```

As long as these files are in the [current directory](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html), they should load just fine.